# Input reading using scanf hangs

Tags: c, scanf

I am programming in C and i have a problem when i run a program in the cmd terminal. here is the code i use:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int num;

    printf("enter a number: ");
    scanf("%i\n", &num);

    for(int n = 1; n < num + 1; n++){
        printf("%i\n", n);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Generally, everything works like it should, exept for one thing.
 when I enter a number, nothing happens. there is no output, until I write anything and press Enter, and only then the number appear.

this is a screenshot of what it looks like.
here is enter the number (and press enter) but nothing happens: http://prntscr.com/deum9a

and this is how it looks like after i entered something random nad all the numbers popped up: http://prntscr.com/deumyn

if anyone knows how to fix this, please tell me (:

Comment: The scanf will be in the execution until enter key is pressed. Are you pressing the enter key right after you enter a number? If yes, what does console show? If no, then it works that way.

Answer (score 4):

Remove the `\n` from `scanf()`

```
scanf("%i", &num);
```

When you have a whitespace character in the format string, `scanf()` will ignore any number of whtiespaces you input and thus the ENTER you do doesn't terminate the input reading. Basically, you'll be forced to input a non whitespace character *again* in order complete the `scanf()` call.

Generally, `scanf()` is considered bad for input reading. So, considering using `fgets()` and parsing the input using `sscanf()`.

See: [Why does everyone say not to use scanf? What should I use instead?](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html)

Comment: thanks is worked! and ill look for some other input methods (: